# How can I enforce a compiler warning or error for namespace conflicts?

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, namespaces

Consider I have the following:

- `FrameworkA`, which defines class `Foo`
- `FrameworkB`, which also defines class `Foo`
- A file in `FrameworkA` which imports `FrameworkB`

How can I get Xcode to generate either a warning or error on any line that makes references to `Foo` without using the namespace qualifier?

For example:

```
let a = FrameworkA.Foo() // fine, no warning or error
let b = FrameworkB.Foo() // fine, no warning or error
let c = Foo()            // at a minimum, a warning
```

---

I understand completely that if we are in `FrameworkA`, then the third example is equivalent to `FrameworkA.Foo()`, but I would like for Xcode to generate a warning or error.

Consider the scenario when class `Foo` has existed in `FrameworkB` for a long time, and the line of code in question has always intended to point at the class `Foo` defined in `FrameworkB`, but at some later point in the future, someone added class `Foo` into `FrameworkA` for some reason.  This would change the behavior of the line in the file.

I would like Xcode to generate compile time warnings or errors any time something defined in multiple frameworks imported into a file is used without the namespace being explicitly declared.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think at this point Xcode supports this unfortunately - some less fruitful solutions:

- Open a [radar task](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), and hope that Apple fixes it.
- Prefix your classes (as we used to do with Obj-C)

The second option should be viable for most projects; instead of Foo and Foo, you will have `LIBAFoo`, `LIBBFoo`, but in practice, with more meaningful prefixes i.e. **CA** → **C**ore **A**nimation.

Comment: This sort of flies directly in the face of all the posts around Stack Overflow suggesting you don't need to prefix your classes any more because we have namespaces.

Comment: To be honest, I have been using both approaches in my Swift projects, and so far, I am still a fan of using the prefixes; it gives you an extra mental hint on where the code belongs and helps you along with code extraction and decoupling. That said, Xcode should definitely have some warning here; I remember, if you do this in Java, the compiler would complain about an ambiguous namespace.